# Xamarin.Froms MarkupExtension used in Picker.Items

Tags: xaml, translation, xamarin.forms, picker, markup-extensions

I've written an markup extension for translating strings using the resources.

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    private readonly ILocalizationService _localizationService;

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public TranslateExtension()
    {
        _localizationService = Mvx.Resolve<ILocalizationService>();
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return "";

        return _localizationService.GetString(Text);
    }
}
```

It's working fine if I use it in Attributes of XAML Elements like:

```
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate DebugView}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
```

But now I want to provide a list of strings in `Picker.Items`.

```
<Picker SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Title="{i18n:Translate State}">
    <Picker.Items>
        <i18n:TranslateExtension Text="OnState"></i18n:TranslateExtension>
        <i18n:TranslateExtension Text="OffState"></i18n:TranslateExtension>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

I don't get it to work. Only if I use **one** `TranslateExtension` element within `Picker.Items`, it's correctly shown. Otherwise it crashes (*'TranslateExtension' cannot be converted to type 'System.String'*). I tried a lot of different styles of writing the elements, but I had no success. What is the correct way to write it?

Comment: It almost looks like a bug but I can't be certain. Just as something quick to try for a workaround, does overriding the ToString() method in the TranslateExtension work. So the ToString returns the translated extension.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. But I have no hope, because the default `ToString` wasn't used. I've even tried an implicit and explicit cast operator ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<Picker SelectedIndex="0" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" Title="{i18n:Translate State}">
    <Picker.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <i18n:TranslateExtension Text="OnState"></i18n:TranslateExtension>
            <i18n:TranslateExtension Text="OffState"></i18n:TranslateExtension>
        </x:Array>
    </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

Try this

Comment: please add more description regarding your answer.

Comment: I have reported the issue in Bugzilla. see https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58155